# For $a,b>0$, $c>1$, and $n=3,4,\dots$ is $|ca^n+(-b)^n|\leq(ca^2+b^2)^{n/2}$ always true?

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b>0$, $c>1$, and $n=3,4,\dots$, then is
\begin{equation}
|ca^n+(-b)^n|\leq(ca^2+b^2)^{n/2},
\end{equation}
true for all possible combinations of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Since $|ca^n + (-b)^n| \leqslant |ca^n| + |(-b)^n| = ca^n + b^n$, it suffices to prove that$$
ca^n + b^n \leqslant (ca^2 + b^2)^{\frac{n}{2}},
$$
i.e.$$
(ca^n + b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leqslant (ca^2 + b^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$

Next, a more general proposition will be proved. For simplicity, take logarithms first.

> Given $x_1, \cdots, x_m \geqslant 0$ and $λ_1, \cdots, λ_m \geqslant 1$, then$$
> f(t) = \frac{1}{t} \ln\left(\sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t\right)
> $$
>   is decreasing for $t > 0$.

**Proof:** Without loss of generality, assume $x_1, \cdots, x_m > 0$. Since$$
f'(t) = -\frac{1}{t^2} \ln\left(\sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t\right) + \frac{1}{t} \frac{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t \ln x_k}{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t},
$$
then for $t > 0$,$$
f'(t) \leqslant 0 \Longleftrightarrow \left(\sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t\right) \ln\left(\sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t\right) \geqslant t \sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t \ln x_k.
$$
Note that $λ_1, \cdots, λ_m \geqslant 1$, thus\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \left(\sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t\right) \ln\left(\sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t \ln\left(\sum_{j = 1}^m λ_j x_j^t\right)\\
&\geqslant \sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t \ln(λ_k x_k^t) \geqslant \sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t \ln(x_k^t) = t \sum_{k = 1}^m λ_k x_k^t \ln x_k.
\end{align*}
Therefore $f(t)$ is decreasing for $t > 0$.

Now, set $m = 2$ and $x_1 = a$, $x_2 = b$, $λ_1 = c$, $λ_2 = 1$, by $f(n) \leqslant f(2)$ there is$$
\frac{1}{n} \ln(ca^n + b^n) \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \ln(ca^2 + b^2),
$$
i.e.$$
(ca^n + b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leqslant (ca^2 + b^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: prove first that $\,\big(c+x^n\big)^2 \le \big(c+x^2\big)^n\,$ for $\,c \ge 1, x \ge 0, n \ge 2\,$, using for example the binomial expansion, noting that $\,\color{red}{c^2} \le \color{red}{c^n}\,$ and $\,\color{blue}{2cx^n}\,$ is no larger than either of the two blue terms on the RHS depending on whether $\,x \ge 1\,$ (when $\,x^n \le x^{2n-2}\,$) or $\,x \le 1\,$ (when $\,x^n \le x^{2}\,$):

$$\require{cancel}
\color{red}{c^2} + \color{blue}{2cx^n} + \cancel{x^{2n}} \le \color{red}{c^n} + \color{blue}{n \cdot c^{n-1}x^2}  + \ldots + \color{blue}{n \cdot c x^{2n-2}} + \cancel{x^{2n}}
$$

Then, use the above for $\,x=b/a\,$, multiply the inequality by $\,a^{2n}\,$ etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  While the other answers address a more general solution, this one is the easiest to follow.

Answer (score 2):

This is true and a pretty weak statement. Here is a much simplified and direct proof for the setup and equivalent general proposition of Alex Francisco

> Given $x_1, \cdots, x_m \geqslant 0,\,λ_1, \cdots, λ_m \geqslant 1$ and $t>1$, then
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_kx_k^t<\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_kx_k\bigg)^t.$$

Proof: $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_kx_k^t}{\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_kx_k\bigg)^t}=\sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_k^{1-t}\alpha_k^t<\sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k=1,$$
since obviously $\lambda_k^{1-t}<1$, and $\alpha_k:=\frac{\lambda_kx_k}{\sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_kx_k}\in[0,1]\implies \alpha_k^t<\alpha_k \bigwedge \sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k=1$.

Comment: I seem to be following you proof but how is the general proposition you wrote of the same form as the problem? It seems like the inequality is of a different form from what I am interested in.  Am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: The problem I posted is of the form $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}\lambda_{k}x_{k}^t\right)^{1/t}\leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}\lambda_{k}x_{k}^2\right)^{1/2}$. Which seems different from what you posted.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson: Substitute $y_k:=x_k^2$ into your inequality and square both sides, what do you get?

Comment: I see now. Thank you for the clarification.